# how to take backup of mysql remote database using java swing

Tags: mysql, database, backup, remote-access

How to take backup of myphpadmin remote or online server database using java swing.

This is showing error of connection. What to do for mysqld.exe for backup.

```
Process p;       
try {            
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        url="jdbc:mysql://188.188.188.188:3306/Datatable";
          user="datatable";
          password="123";
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password) ;

        p=runtime.exec("mysqldump  -datatable -p123 --add-drop-database server -B datatable -r"+path); 
        //  "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe -uroot -p --add-drop-database server  -B newproject -r"+path); 

        int processComplete = p.waitFor();
        if (processComplete==1) {
            jLabel1.setText("Backup Created Succuss");
        }else{
            jLabel1.setText("Can't Create backup");
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What can i do for backup the database.

Comment: Refer https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-backup-and-restore.php

Comment: i doing this in netbeans

Comment: Do you wanna backup programmically or manually